# What really is the difference between Endogenous variable and dependent variable?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, inference

I was learning about Factor analysis.

Then, from there, somehow I reached at some site to learn about SEM [here](http://www.statisticshowto.com/simultaneous-equations-model/).

Can anyone help with the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually this website is kinda confusing. On your link and the explanation of endogenous variables it tells us dependent variables are different, on the other side (dependent variables) it is written that:

> The dependent variable is also called a response variable or
> endogenous variable in statistical modeling. [1](http://www.statisticshowto.com/dependent-variable-definition/)

Since most papers use those as synonyms it is understandable to be confused. An endogenous variable is dependent of other variables **inside** of the statistical System.  Also you see the dependency in your model.

> endogenous (comparative more endogenous, superlative most endogenous):
>
> -Produced, originating or growing from **within**.
>
> -Of a natural process, or caused by factors within the body. [2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endogenous#English)

The dependent variables can be more because it can describe statements, like a result of the system. So it also exists outside of the system. (The Explanandum) [3](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/%7Edelittle/Encyclopedia%20entries/Endogenous%20variable.htm)

It strongly depends on the field you are researching. Dependent variables are often used as response, an outcome or criterion variable. Independent variables are often used as predictors, the causes, or explanatory variables.

In statistically terms you mostly see them uses as synonyms (like mentioned above).

In short you could say, endogenous variables are a fact of dependency in your model and depend variables can also be outside your model, a statement before or a result of the model.

---

[1](http://www.statisticshowto.com/dependent-variable-definition/) Dependent Variable: Definition and Examples. Statistics How To. Retrieved July 19, 2018, from http://www.statisticshowto.com/dependent-variable-definition/

[2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endogenous#English) endogenous. servent - Wiktionary. Retrieved July 19, 2018, from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endogenous#English

[3](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/%7Edelittle/Encyclopedia%20entries/Endogenous%20variable.htm) Endogenous variable: A factor in a causal model or causal system whose value is determined by the states of other variables in. Costume Design. Retrieved July 19, 2018, from [http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~delittle/Encyclopedia%20entries/Endogenous%20variable.htm](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/%7Edelittle/Encyclopedia%20entries/Endogenous%20variable.htm)